# watson speech to text: unable to transcode data stream application/octet-stream -> audio/x-float-array

Tags: go, voip, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, rtp

I am trying to send raw rtp stream from the voip call to IBM watson(speech-to-text) api by using their golang SDK, but getting below response back from them.

```
"error": "unable to transcode data stream application/octet-stream -> audio/x-float-array "
```

By looking over old issue, it looks like they don't recognize data as valid audio source.

I am using the model `en-US_NarrowbandModel` with below headers.

```
headers.Set("Content-Type", "audio/mulaw;rate=8000;channels=1")
headers.Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
```

The rtp packet was encoded using PCMU with sampling rate of 8000. From the sdp

```
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
```

I have even tried setting the `endianness` to little and big endian but no avail.

The same setup is working in the python sdk, where they let you to use streaming function.
I am wondering if missed something from the watson golang sdk version.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.